# How to stop regenerating the wall after first click?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I just coded a game that needs the wall to be generated forever randomly (just like the walls in Flappy Bird), but every time when I touched the screen, it started to generate again which ended up with generating too much walls. Is there any methods I could use when clicking the screen (to make player jump) without generating too much walls?

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: Hey, sorry I tried to attach a photo but it seems doesn't work, so I'm gonna paste them here:

Comment: override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
          //  movingGround.start()
            
            self.aGreenCan.run(jumpAction)
            
            wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(seconds: 5)
            
            
            

            }

Comment: Well the reason why you're having this problem is because you're adding wallGenerator.startGen.... within touchesBegan. Try removing it and add it somewhere like didmovetoview

Comment: I tried to move it outside but it starts generating right at the beginning, what if I only want it to start when I touched the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so based on our conversation in the comments, what you would want to do is create a boolean like so

```
var gameStarted = Bool()// outside of didMoveToView

  override func touchesBegan() {

  if gameStarted == false{
     gameStarted = true 
     movingGround.start() 
     // add whatever code is left

      }

 }
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped. If it helped, would you please click the check mark and accept the answer? @RachelZhang

Comment: Hey sorry for my delayed response, and I just checked it right now[I'm not sure if I clicked the right button, but did you get the mark?]

Comment: It's understandable. Yes I did receive it. Glad I could help!